# How to add same value to a list multiple times in one go in Dart/Flutter

Tags: dart

Let's say I have an empty list.
If I want to add a certain number of letters "g" to this list. for example 30 40 etc. the number I send may change.
Is there a way to do this in one go without using a loop?
What is it, if any?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/fillRange.html
I need a method like fillRange.
FillRange does not work on an empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the list is empty, don't bother using it. Just generate a new list with [List.filled](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.filled.html):

```dart
final list = List.filled(30, 'g');
```

---

EDIT: For completeness, here is how to use the above with an existing list:

```dart
final list = <String>[...];

// Mutate original list
list.addAll(List.filled(30, 'g'));

// Create new list with spread syntax
final newList = [
  ...list,
  ...List.filled(30, 'g'),
];
```